# 'flutter run' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flutter, dart, command

I try to run 'flutter run' but it give me error :
[image]

I added the flutter to the Path, and it did recognized when I run 'flutter doctor'[image]

what could be the problem that it not recognized the 'flutter run' ? I try it in cmd, in vs code.

Comment: `&` is an invalid character for a path. Rename your folder to `flutter_dart` or similar.

Comment: did you try system environment Path? and then restart the device?

Comment: the path is "C:\Users\liron\Documents\flutter_dart\flutter\bin" and I did restart after

Answer (score 0):

try to enable hardware acceleration, in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)